# Is there a way to Regex-check a parameter within my custom `dotnet new` template?

Tags: .net, regex, templating

I have a [custom `dotnet new` template](https://github.com/lfmundim/Blip.Api.Template.K8s) that kickstarts an API project with some orchestration. It works well, however I needed to add a rule.

There is a parameter within [`template.json`](https://github.com/lfmundim/Blip.Api.Template.K8s/blob/master/content/.template.config/template.json)

```
"aks":{
      "type": "parameter",
      "datatype": "string",
      "replaces": "blipapitemplate",
      "isRequired": true,
      "fileRename": "blipapitemplate"
    }
```

that I need it to have a certain pattern: `lower-kebab-case`. **Is there a way to enforce it?** Like fail to create/throw an exception if the value given does not match a regex or something

I tried reading [the reference](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Reference-for-template.json) and googling but no luck.

Comment: Does this help at all: https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-Parameter-Generators#regex

Comment: Not at all =/ that teaches me to replace stuff via a regex, but I need one step earlier: I need to check if a parameter used on attempting to initialize the template (e.g: `dotnet new my-template --parameter this-guy-right-here`) follows a certain regex

Answer (score 0):

I think the person who posted this guide still gave the answer:
https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-Parameter-Generators#regex

I'm finding myself in the same scenario, and I don't think there's a way to "throw an exception", but there is at least a way to modify. For example, I want the "name" of mine to "start with" a value, so I'll have a generated parameter that uses the "name" and prepends "Nx" if it's not already there. Maybe you can do something like that, where you force it into a pascal case? Alternatively, you could add msbuild targets that validate and throw errors after it's already been created.

Comment: it'd be nice if you summarized the useful info from the linked resource. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587